# Equal width list child & break the line

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, html-table, responsive

What I'm trying to achieve is to make a kind of responsive / fluid navigation which will be box shaped. It means that I will have 6 list elements, which in condition of 100% width, will be separated into two rows, each with 3 childs.

Like:

|item 1| |item 2| |item 3|

|item 4| |item 5| |item 6|

When the screen will go smaller, then it will make a stack/collapse, one item per row (like with bootstrap columns.

This is what I've got currently:

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">

      <ul class="courses-types list-group">
         <li class="list-group-item">item 1</li>
         <li class="list-group-item">item 2</li>
         <li class="list-group-item">item 3</li>
         <li class="list-group-item">item 4</li>
         <li class="list-group-item">item 5</li>
         <li class="list-group-item">item 6</li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

and css

```
.courses-types {
  padding:0;
  width:100%;
  background:pink;
  display:table;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 10px;
}
.courses-types, .courses-types li {
  list-style-type: none;
  list-style-position: inside;
  text-align: center;
}

.courses-types li {
  display:table-cell;
  background:#cecece;
  padding:1em;
  width:calc(100%/3);
  border:0;
}
```

current code has few issues - even if width its calculated based on 100% width, still the childs are not equal. Second issue - have no idea how to make it colapsable after 3rd element (when big size screen) and after each (when small one). Project is based on bootstrap 3.3.7.

Comment: you cannot have wrapping using table layout, consider Flexbox or inline-block or even float

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use flexbox instead. 
This could will give you the desired layout.

```css
.list-group {
   display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.list-group-item {
  flex-basis: 33.3333%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">

      <ul class="courses-types list-group">
         <li class="list-group-item">item 1</li>
         <li class="list-group-item">item 2</li>
         <li class="list-group-item">item 3</li>
         <li class="list-group-item">item 4</li>
         <li class="list-group-item">item 5</li>
         <li class="list-group-item">item 6</li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: thanks a million! Just extended the code with media query dedicated to mobile devices.